# Perform mathematical expression written as a string using variables values from dictionary (python)

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have this operation as a string variable:

```
formula = '{a} + {b}'
```

And I have a dictionary such as

```
data = {'a': 3, 'b': 4}
```

Is there such a functionality in some library where:

```
evaluate(operation = formula, variables = data)
```

gives:

```
7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not recomended, you can use `eval()`. Check out:

```
>>> data = {'a': 3, 'b': 4}
>>> eval('{a} + {b}'.format(**data))
>>> 7
```

`eval()` will try to execute the given string as python code.
For more information about python `format` you can take a look at the really nice [pyformat](https://pyformat.info/) site.

Comment: Thank you very much for this insight. It also helped me find numexpr. I need to play a bit more with them

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Python3 you can do something like this with string formatting:

```
>>> import ast
>>> data = {'a': 3, 'b': 4}
>>> formula = '{a} + {b}'
>>> res_string = formula.format(a=data['a'], b=data['b'])
>>> res = ast.literal_eval(res_string)
>>> print(res)
7
```

Or even better as pointed by Steven in the comments:

```
res_string = formula.format(**data)
```

---

Or if you are using Python3.6 you can even do this with the cool f-string:

```
>>> f"{sum(data.values())}"
'7'
```

Comment: @StevenSummers Thanks. Updated

Answer (score 1):

First you need to parse your string, then you need to have a proper dictionary in order to map the founded operators to their equivalent functions, which you can use `operator` module for this aim:

```
In [54]: from operator import add

In [55]: operators = {'+': add}  # this is an example, if you are dealing with more operations you need to add them to this dictionary

In [56]: def evaluate(formula, data):
             a, op, b = re.match(r'{(\w)} (\W) {(\w)}', formula).groups()
             op = operators[op]
             a, b = data[a], data[b]
             return op(a, b)
   ....: 

In [57]: evaluate(formula, data)
Out[57]: 7
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply... this should be more efficient when you one only need to solve one type of equation :)